# How to create .dic file for turkish language in cmusphinx

Tags: speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I installed "sphinxbase" and "pocketsphinx" on windows and run the "PocketSphinxDemo" on eclipse and on my phone.
Next i want to create  Turkish language for this application.It is enough to understand a few words or sentences as beginning so that it could be easy.
I could not found ready Turkish model on Voxforge. 
Is there any other website that i can find or any tool that i can create easily.

I used imtool but dic file pronunciation is english.
How can i create dic file for turkish language.

Answer (score 2):

You need a list of words first of all. After that you can use [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) rules to create a phonetic dictionary:

```
espeak -v tr -x
Türkçe 
tYRktS'E
```

You only need to parse the output an put it in the dictionary in alpha-only format.You just neet create a map to letter-only phoneset, not necessary a map to arpabet.  Open the text pad and create a map:

```
t t
y yy
r rr
k k
e ee
S' sh
```

So in the end you get entries like this:

```
türkçe t yy rr k t sh ee
```

That's it. There is no requirement to use ARPABet. For more details see the [acoustic model training tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam)

Comment: I used espeak and generated ipa symbols of words.Now how can i convert them as CMU sphinx phoneset format ARPABet.

Comment: There is no need to map to ARPAbet, you need just a random map to letter-only phoneset. I've updated the anwer with the example.

Comment: How can i map these symbols? big R means rr, small r means r, S' means sh as i understand. what about 'a or @ means etc.. how can i find them.

Comment: You can select any reasonable mapping as long as they are unique. For example map a to a and @ to ax. Unleash your mind.